# How to automatically resize the vertical bar in a set comprehension?

Tags: macros, math-mode

I have a simple command which I use to write set comprehensions so that the braces automatically resize with respect to size of the enclosed arguments, e.g.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\lbrace #1\right\rbrace}

\begin{equation*}
\set{x \in X \mid x > \frac{1}{2}}  
\end{equation*}
% Produces something like: { x : X | x > 1/2 }
```

However, the `\mid` vertical bar wont resize like the braces `{ .. }` do. How can I get the `\mid` to resize as well?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use `\middle|` instead of `\mid` like

```
\[ \left\{ x \in X \middle| x > \frac{1}{2}\right\} \]
```

or with better spacing

```
\[ \left\{ x \in X \,\middle|\, x > \frac{1}{2}\right\} \]
```

(I think this requires a somewhat modern TeX-distribution.)

Comment: @Andrew: It is an eTeX primitive (not included in the original TeX). But nowadays LaTeX always is run on the pdftex engine, which includes the eTeX stuff.

Comment: What if you want it to be slightly taller, so that extends slightly above and below the height of the brackets? Is there a way to adjust this?

Answer (score 17):

I think the best idea is to use the braket package, which provides markup for these sorts of constructions, for which the brackets and "pipes" expand where necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Leaving a comment here for future reference: [Braket](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/braket.html) lets you write `\Set{ x | 0<x<5}` etc., expanding the | as necessary.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a nice solution using [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), which is quite versatile and produces the right spacing (thin space withing braces, and thick space around the mid symbol):

```
\usepackage{mathtools}    
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\setc[2]{\{}{\}}{\,#1 \;\delimsize\vert\; #2\,}
```

Now if you use the starred version of the macro you get the desired result:

```
\setc*{x \in X}{x > \frac{1}{2}}
```

[image]

You can even adjust to a different size if you think that the braces are too big, with the syntax

```
\setc[\Big]{x \in X}{x > \frac{1}{2}}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to modify this so that \setc adjusts the size while \setc* does not?

Answer (score 12):

There is the `\middle` command, it is like `\left` and `\right` but for the middle =)

However, LaTeX does not consider `\mid` to be a delimiter, so you have to use pipe instead (or vertical bar).

Comment: _However, LaTeX does not consider \mid to be a delimiter_  — Is there a way to make it do so? I would consider this the best solution in terms of pretty source code.

Comment: If you want pretty source code, why not just define your own macro for set notation, instead of writing `\{ ... | ... \}` all the time? I have defined in my macro set `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[2]\lbrace\rbrace{#1\;\delimsize\vert\;#2}`. The spacing `\;` can be further optimized [according to egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36319/how-to-make-expanding-middle-delimitors-like-in-the-braket-package/36328#comment72424_36328). // As to the question you asked: `\mid` is defined to be a `\mathrel` (see https://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/tex/latex/fntguide/node18.html)..

Comment: .. unfortunately the original TeX engine does not have a "middle delimiter" (there's only `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`), so you cannot really declare a delimiter in your sense. An alternative is to not use `\left` and `\middle` and `\right` and hand code the sizes yourself using `\big` and friends. If you do that there is a `\bigm` version suitable for use here. See [this answer of Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52905/119).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me, possibly the horizontal spacing around the bar needs adjusting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\my@set}[1]{\left\lbrace #1\right\rbrace}
\newcommand{\my@cset}[2]{%
 \left\lbrace #1\vphantom{#2}\right\vert%
 \left.\vphantom{#1}#2\right\rbrace}

\def\my@first#1|#2\relax{#1}
\def\my@second#1|#2\relax{#2}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{%
\edef\my@given{#1}
\edef\my@start{\my@first #1|\relax}%
\ifx\my@start\my@given
\my@set{#1}
\else
\edef\my@last{\my@second #1\relax}%
\my@cset{\my@start}{\my@last}%
\fi}

\begin{document}


\[
  \set{x \in X \int_0^1 | y \in Y} \; \set{x \in X \int_0^1 y \in Y}
\]

\[
\set{x | y} \set{a b}
\]

\end{document}
```