# How can you address the size of surrounding parentheses whose size is determined by \left and \right?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automatically resize the vertical bar in a set comprehension?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448/how-to-automatically-resize-the-vertical-bar-in-a-set-comprehension)

Trying to type the formula for a conditional probability like this

```
\mathrm{P} \left( whatever \mid whatever \right) = ...,
```

I'd like to have `\mid` the same size as the left and right parentheses.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `\middle|` or for a double `\middle|\middle|`

```
\[ \left( \frac{a}{b^2}+1\middle| f(x)\right)\]
```

Comment: Arg, 12sec to late ... I would have used `\middle\vert`, but `\middle|` seems to do the same.

Comment: I was 29 seconds too late...

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks, works fine (I just have to adjust the spaces around the | a little)!

Comment: @Martin: Sorry, but you could have been a little less altruistic and first answer the question before beautifying it.

Comment: `\vert` is the same as `\|`

Comment: @Herbert: `\vert` is the same as `|`, `\Vert` is the same as `\|`

Comment: sure, that's what I wanted to say ...

Answer (score 4):

`\middle` doesn't add spaces around the symbol it produces and treats it as an ordinary symbol, like when we say `\bigg|` or even `\bigg(`. On the other hand it can't be put inside `\mathrel`.

The problem might arise when when `\middle` is used in a subscript; one can say either of

```
\left( something \nonscript\;\middle|\nonscript\; something \right)
\left( something \mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} something \right)
```

and the result will be the same as if we used `\mid` (of course if we decide that this vertical bar must be treated as a relation symbol). This is for writing macros that use the `\middle` feature, as in direct input one knows what space is necessary.