# Sizing for 'given that' symbol - vertical bar

Tags: math-mode, symbols, scaling

I want to write an equation with `$\mid$`, but it is too small, can i make it bigger in any way?

I am kinda new to TeX so i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps [How can you address the size of surrounding parentheses whose size is determined by `\left` and `\right`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17482/5764) can help... not sure about the usage of `\mid` in your case. More detail?

Comment: Well, `\Bigm|` would help? And what exactly do you need it for (because there're at least 5 different meanings of `|`)? Maybe you can help us in helping you by providing a [Minimal (non-)Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)...

Comment: Are you sure that you want `\mid` (which is usually used to *such that* meaning) or do you want a vertical bar to denote the absolute value, for example, on a fraction? If you want the second option, use `\left|...\right|`.

Comment: I'm not sure to have ever heard of a "given that" symbol. Can you show what it is and a context where it's used?

Comment: @egreg: I took it to mean conditional probability, e.g., P(X = x|Y = y).

Answer (score 27):

**2017 Update**: Since `\mid` is a *relation*, under normal circumstances the spaces manually inserted around `\middle|` should be thick `\;` instead of thin `\,`. See table on p.170 of the TEXbook.

---

Instead of `\mid`, you can use `\middle` command to enlarge vertical delimiter and insert spaces manually, here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[S=\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n}\;\middle|\;X_i\sim\chi^2(k)\right)\]
\[\left.\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i+Y_i}{n}\;\middle|\;X\sim\chi^2_k\;\middle|\;Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)\right.\]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Better yet, we can make a custom command for our conveniences:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@giventhatstar}[2]{\left(#1\;\middle|\;#2\right)}
\newcommand{\@giventhatnostar}[3][]{#1(#2\;#1|\;#3#1)}
\newcommand{\giventhat}{\@ifstar\@giventhatstar\@giventhatnostar}
\makeatother
```

It works sorta like `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` in `mathtools`, for example:

```
\[\giventhat{f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}}{x=1,2,3,\dotsc}\]
\[\giventhat[\big]{f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}}{x=1,2,3,\dotsc}\]
\[\giventhat[\Big]{f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}}{x=1,2,3,\dotsc}\]
\[\giventhat*{f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}}{x=1,2,3,\dotsc}\]
```

will give you:

[image]

Comment: `\cdots` is not the proper dots to use here

Comment: See also my addition

Comment: Really helpfull, thanks. However, when adding the commands at the beginning of the document I had to make some changes and include the \ensuremath{...} command:

\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@giventhatstar}[2]{\ensuremath{\left({#1}\;\middle|\;{#2}\right)}}
\newcommand{\@giventhatnostar}[3][]{#1(#2\;#1|\;#3#1)}
\newcommand{\giventhat}{\@ifstar\@giventhatstar\@giventhatnostar}
\makeatother

Answer (score 23):

Sounds like conditional probability. In that case I usually recommend our students to use something similar to

```
\newcommand\given[1][]{\:#1\vert\:}
```

Which will be manually scalled via,  say

```
\given[\Big]
```

Then the code makes sense when read

---

ADDITION. Building further on Francis' suggestion `\given` can be build into his macros such that the macros only takes one argument.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\givenbase[1][]{\:#1\lvert\:}
\let\given\givenbase
\newcommand\sgiven{\givenbase[\delimsize]}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Basics[1](){\let\given\sgiven #1}
\newcommand\Average{E\Basics}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \Basics{X} \qquad \Basics[\Big]{ X \given Y}\\
  \Average{X} \qquad \Average[\Big]{ X \given Y}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\operatorname{E}` instead of `E`?

Comment: It might be yes. Though I think most people think of it in the same manner as `f(x)`, i.e. just a function. Some people use an upright `E`, some people even use `\mathbb{E}`. Depends on the tradition.

Answer (score 5):

This uses features of the `scalerel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\noindent You can stretch it to a size:\\
$A \mid 
\mathrel{\stretchto{\mid}{3ex}} 
\mathrel{\stretchto{\mid}{4ex}}
B$\\
or you can stretch it to fit something else:\\
$ \stretchrel{\mid}{\displaystyle\frac{A}{B}} $\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `\left.\right|`

For example
`$$\mathbb{E}(Y^3) = \left.\frac{d^3 M_Z(t)}{d t^3}\right|_{t=0}$$`

[image]