# How to make expanding middle delimitors like in the braket package

Tags: brackets, delimiters

The [braket](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/braket) package has convenient commands like `\Braket` and `\Set`, where `|` are automatically expanded vertically. This allows to easily typeset expressions like

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
$$\Braket{\psi |i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\phi}$$ 
\end{document}
```

I'd like to do the same thing with other delimiters, for example to typeset conditional probabilities like `$P(A=\frac12|B)$`.

*Edit to clarify the question*
I'm interested to cases where I don't know which size of the `|`-sign is the biggest. An example could be `$P(A=\frac12|B=2^{2^2})$`.

Comment: Remember to *never* use `$$` in LaTeX documents.

Comment: Why ? Because it is more difficult to balance than '\[\]' ? The latter involve 6-times more keystrokes on my (French) keyboard, so I'm wondering whether the reason is really compelling ?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `\middle|`

```
$P\left( A = \frac{1}{2} \middle| B \right)$
```

Comment: One should note that `\middle|` doesn't add space around the bar and so `\;\middle|\;` should be used. Even better, `\nonscript\;\middle|\nonscript\;` if this is used in a macro for something that can go into subscripts or superscripts.

Comment: @egreg: I usually use `\,\middle\,` in macros, but `\;` is better.

Comment: isn't `\middle` [e-tex](http://tex.loria.fr/moteurs/etex_ref.html#middle) specific ? If yes wouldn't that h-complicate the exchanges of documents with colleagues ?

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans Only very old distributions don't use by default an e-TeX enabled engine for LaTeX

Comment: OK. Then I'll try this and come back when I encounter an overconservative colleague :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One could also use `\vert` as an additional nested bracket like in:

```
$P\left( \left. A = \frac{1}{2} \,\right\vert B \right)$
```

Comment: This would only work as expected if `B` in your example isn't awkwardly big. Otherwise `\right\vert` won't scale to the appropriate length. In such a case `\right\vert` and `\right)` won't have the same height.