# fraction equation out of the fraction line

Tags: equations, overleaf

I'm using an overleaf springer nature latex template. It can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq):
I tried many packages to get this equation to appear right without success.
It appears like [image: this]. If I use the Elsevier latex template overleaf or online equation editor the equation will appear just fine. Any help, please.

```
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout

\jyear{2021}%

%% as per the requirement new theorem styles can be included as shown below
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
%%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]% meant for sectionwise numbers
%% optional argument [theorem] produces theorem numbering sequence instead of independent numbers for Proposition
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}% to get separate numbers for theorem and proposition etc.

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}

\section{Equations}\label{sec1}

% EQUATION 1
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq.1}
P(h(x)|S) = \frac{P(h(x) \cdot P(S|h(x))}{P(S)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I haven't tested this, but it looks like there are more opening parentheses than closing ones.  Count them carefully to make sure they match, and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- consider @Barbara Beeton comment, and
- instead of `|` you had to use the `\mid`:

```
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout

\jyear{2021}%

\begin{document}

\section{Equations}
\label{sec1}

\begin{equation}\label{Eq.1}
P(h(x)\mid S) = \frac{P(h(x)) \cdot P(S\mid h(x))}{P(S)} %, 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Nice find! :). Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52901

Comment: Regarding Barbara's comment: I did *not* see unbalanced brackets.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, She is right. Instead `P(h(x) \cdot ...` should be `P(h(x)) \cdot ...)`

Comment: Ah, I see, but I did not think that this is related to the problem. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, apparently contributed. Without closed parenthesis I get error: `missing $`. It seems that `sn-jnl` is more pedantic and picky as `article` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Works for me?! Please provide a complete code example, see [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
P(h(x)|S) = \frac{P(h(x) \cdot P(S|h(x))}{P(S)}
\label{Eq.1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AbdullaAburomman I recommend that you provide a compilable code example and include it in your question. That makes things much easier for others to help (less guesswork). The linked template seems complex - so please boil it down to the essentials regarding the problem.

Comment: "I recommend that you provide a compilable code example and include it in your question".
I did that by re-editing my post.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works. :-)