# Using boxes to define an adjusting (Dirac) bracket

Tags: macros, boxes, brackets

I'd like to define a set of adjusting bracket, called in physics Dirac brackets.

This brackets accept three arguments, separated by vertical lines, and all of them are enclosed by angles, e.g. in text format would by `<a|b|c>`.

### MWE

A first try would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\bkt[3]{\left< {#1} \left|{#2} \right| {#3} \right>}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \bkt{a}{b}{c}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \bkt{a}{b}{\frac{c}{d}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

As can be seen in the picture, the middle brackets have not the desired size in the second case [image]

### Attempt of a solution

Creating a box with height equal to the max. height of the three arguments, and place the second argument inside the box should solve the problem... but I don't know if doing that is possible.

Does anyone have an idea for solving my problem?

Thank you, and (almost) Merry Christmas.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36319/how-to-make-expanding-middle-delimitors-like-in-the-braket-package

Comment: `\middle` will expand all three vertical bars. I guess that OP wants to expand only the nearest bar.

Comment: Also, consider using `\langle` instead of `<`, and `\rangle` instead of `>` for Bra-Ket notation...

Comment: @Sigur -- i see only two vertical bars.  where's the third one?  i do think that `\Braket` as in the cited answer solves the problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, ow, sorry. I should be sleeping :-) Of course, only two bars (but 3 arguments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\middle` for the middle delimiters... and more than one if needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\newcommand\bkt[3]{\left< #1 \;\middle|\; #2 \;\middle|\; #3 \right>}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x &= \bkt{a}{b}{c} \\
  y &= \bkt{a}{b}{\frac{c}{d}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note that putting math elements inside braces could strip certain spacing, so I've removed them in the definition of `\bkt`. I've also added some spacing around `\middle|` (as suggested in [How to make expanding middle delimitors like in the `braket` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36319/5764)). For a reference of horizontal spaces, see [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764).

Answer (score 6):

Let us call *physics* as *physics* without re-inventing anything ;-). You can use `physics` package. For details `texdoc physics` or [texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net) (pages 6 and 7, section 2.6).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \mel*{a}{b}{c}\\
  \mel{a}{b}{c} \\
  \bra{a}b\ket{c}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \mel**{a}{b}{\frac{c}{d}}\\
  \mel{a}{b}{\frac{c}{d}} \\
  \bra{a}b\ket{\frac{c}{d}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]