# Two lines in an equation of one line

Tags: equations

What I want to do is to include two lines at the begging in an one-line equation, just like in the following picture.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea in order to achieve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `\max_{x\in\mathcal{J}(k)}\left\{...`

Comment: `\max` requires `amsmath`. for a more general discussion of math operators, see [newcommand vs. DeclareMathOperator](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67506/579). for a list of operators defined in this way, see the `amsmath` documentation -- `texdoc amsmath` on a tex live system.

Comment: Depending on how new you are to LaTeX, note that barbara's comment about `amsmath` means that you need `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble of your document.

Comment: @barbarabeeton try `latex \\show\\max` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- yup.  correct.  (i did try to check with `grep` but didn't search for the "correct" string.)  even so, using `amsmath` if one has much math in a document isn't a bad idea.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes agreed anyone typesetting math with latex should use amsmath, but, still I didn't use it below:-)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to make expanding middle delimitors like in the `braket` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36319/5764); [How to automatically resize the vertical bar in a set comprehension?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448/5764)

Comment: To elaborate on David's answer, you are not asking for two lines but for a subscript to max.

Comment: @Werner Ehm, I don't think this question is about the vertical bar, but about the max with subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mathtools` (that loads `amsmath`anyway) and its `DeclarePairedDelimiterX` command, you can have a better spacing for |, and a better control on the size of the braces:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp} 

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[2]{\{}{\}}{#1 \delimsize\vert #2}
\newcommand*\Set[1]{\set*{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\let\emptyset\varnothing    

\begin{document} 
\begin{align}
\tag*{With \texttt{\textbackslash Big}:}       &  \max_{\mathbf x \in \mathcal J(\mathbf K)}\!{\set[\Big]{\sum_{i\in I}\mathcal G_{i  \abs{C_i}}(\mathbf{\Pi}_i, y_i, \emptyset)}{(\mathbf\Pi, y_i)\in \mathcal N(\mathbf x_i)}} \\
\tag*{With \texttt{\textbackslash bigg}:}       & \max_{\mathbf x \in \mathcal J(\mathbf K)}\!{\set[\bigg]{\sum_{i\in I}\mathcal G_{i  \abs{C_i}}(\mathbf{\Pi}_i, y_i, \emptyset)}{(\mathbf\Pi, y_i)\in \mathcal N(\mathbf x_i)}}\\
\tag*{With an implicit \texttt{\textbackslash left}:}        & \max_{\mathbf x \in \mathcal J(\mathbf K)}\!{\Set{\sum_{i\in I}\mathcal G_{i  \abs{C_i}}(\mathbf{\Pi}_i, y_i, \emptyset)}{(\mathbf\Pi, y_i)\in \mathcal N(\mathbf x_i)}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Please always post a complete document not just a fragment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}


\[
\max_{x\in\mathcal{J}(k)}\left\{ \sum_a^b something \middle| something\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd say that the outer fences a excessively large and the `\middle|` needs spacing around it. My solution to a similar problem http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167749/3929

Comment: @daleif yes, agreed. and `something` shouldn't be set in math italic, but I decided not to address those here and concentrate on the question about the subscript to max.