# Problem with a user defined command within alignment

Tags: macros, align

I've created a command `\newcommand{\br}[1]{$\left\{{#1}\right\}$}`
    to provide left and right curly braces surrounding an input.

The usage `\br{g \in G : \theta(g) = M/N}` works perfectly until I try to use 
    it in alignment as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
\ker\theta &= \br{g \in G : \theta(g) = M/N} \\
&= \br{g \in G : (M/N)Ng = M/N}
\end{align*}
```

1. Is there a better macro for enclosing `{}`?
2. Is there a way to use this or a better macro within alignment?

---

**Update**:

There is an alternative to the macro I defined called `\Set` in the [braket](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/braket.html) package. This is due to a comment in [How to automatically resize the vertical bar in a set comprehension?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448/how-to-automatically-resize-the-vertical-bar-in-a-set-comprehension) commented by [ShreevatsaR](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48/shreevatsar).

```
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{align*}
\ker\theta &= \Set{g \in G \colon \theta(g) = M/N} \\
&= \Set{g \in G \colon (M/N)Ng = M/N}
\end{align*}
```

[image: Equation alignment using Set]

Comment: the problem here is that you're including `$...$` in the definition of the command.  the `align*` environment puts you into math mode, so the `$` signs are redundant, and cause an error.  it would be better to omit the `$` signs from the command definition, and instead enter them around the command when you use it.

Comment: `\newcommand{\brr}[1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}` Works like a charm. If you care to drop that as an answer I'll accept it. Thx!

Comment: I'd suggest to use \newcommand{\brr}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\{#1\right\}}} ...

Comment: In the long run it is probably not a good idea to use auto scaling as they have a tendency to become too large in certain cases. I'd suggest building `\br` using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from mathtools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem here is that `align*` (and all the display math environments) put you
automatically into math mode, so including `$...$` in a definition that will
be used in such an environment will result in an error if you use it there.

omit `$` signs from the definition.  if it's then used in text, it's better to
explicitly include them in the input stream -- it will make it obvious that what
is there is math, and thus easier to find when you are looking for something in
your file.

an alternative possibility is to use `\ensuremath` in the definition, so that it
will work equally well whether in or not in math mode.  however, this is not
really recommended, as it obscures the nature of the command.  some additional
reasons for not using it are given here: [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34837).