How to control the size of a symbol in math-mode using number, which is not symbols of pairs?
I used to use sentences like $\left\{f(x)\Big|x\in X\right\}$ to write down a set.
For symbols like "()","[]","{}","\langle\rangle" and stuff, using "\left\right" I can let it get a suitable size of themselves, but I can't do for "|".
Usually I use "\Big" as a suitable size I like, but I met a problem when I write down a set of $2\times 2$-matrix, in which even "\bigg" is not big enough, and "\Bigg" is. I think the next times I use $3\times 3$-matrix it will not work as I expect.
And there're some time I want to use size between "\big" and "\Big". It will be better for me to use a number to control its size, but not just "\big" and "\Big".

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448/how-to-automatically-resize-the-vertical-bar-in-a-set-comprehension. I think you're looking for \middle

In the math tools manual is an example of how I would design a \Set macro including support for scaling the vertical bar

Is there something wrong with \left\{f(x)\left|x\in X\right.\right\}?

It sizes the line to fit everything to its right.  For example,
\left\{f(x)\left|x\in \frac{X}{Y}\right.\right\} produces


You asked, "Is there something wrong with \left\{f(x)\left|x\in X\right.\right\}"? Not wrong, per se, but inefficient. Do give \left\{ f(x) \middle| x\in X \right\} a try.

One could argue that that uneven spacing around the vertical bar is wrong. One can also argue that there are no rights and wrongs...
